# Magento 2: How to remove category sidebar from the pages?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, layered-navigation, sidebar

Yesterday I had applied porto theme after that category sidebar is coming for every category page and product page.
In Category page it is coming in left side and product page coming in right side.
For reference please find the images and website
https://vitalticks.in
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the catalog module page layout. It should be 2 column left. Set it to 1.column and try.

Comment: i have to remove only category sidebar

Comment: In the layout xml files you can use remove="true" for sidebar.  Run static content deploy and cache clean after this.